# Heroku fork - That add-on plan is only available to select users

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, ghost

I have a production-stage app deployed on Heroku. I'd like to fork the app to make a staging environment.

```
Input
heroku fork --from <app_name>-production --to <app_name>-staging

Output
Forking <app_name>-production... done. Forked to <app_name>-staging
Setting buildpacks... done
Adding newrelic:wayne to <app_name>-staging as NEW_RELIC... done
Adding deployhooks:http to <app_name>-staging as DEPLOYHOOKS_HTTP... done
Adding heroku-postgresql:standard-yanari to <app_name>-staging as HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON...!
That add-on plan is only available to select users.
There was an error forking to <app_name>-staging.
```

I'm not sure if I need to update the postgresql database, or purchase some additional add-on through Heroku. Since I'm new and this is my employer's app, I'm reluctant to make any changes that might result in a loss of data. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue with a legacy "dev" plan and the response from Heroku support was...

> Sorry it's a bit of an issue with older apps. The heroku-postgresql:dev plan is no longer available - it's heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev. You could either try a pg:copy to move this app to hobby-dev or use the `--skip-pg` flag to skip the database creation and set that part up manually (you can pg:copy between apps with `heroku pg:copy <source app>::<db name> DATABASE -a <target app>`).

Hope that helps